# What is the current bandwidth or quality of an audio MediaStream in a browser? (WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, browser, webrtc, opus, mediastream

I'm currently building a WebRTC application and want to gather some statistics in order to rate my solution. One metric I'm interested in is the current bandwidth of the received audio (and video) stream. I was able to find the currently used codec at `chrome://webrtc-internals/` (OPUS), but I wasn't able to find numbers about the current quality/bandwidth of the stream (e.g. 128kbit/s).

I already searched the RTCPeerConnection Object for such numbers, but haven't found some. `XXX.RTCconnection.getRemoteStreams()[0].getAudioTracks()[0].getConstraints()` only returns

```
{ 
  deviceId: {}, 
  echoCancellation: {}, 
  facingMode: {}, 
  frameRate: {}, 
  height: {}, 
  mediaSource: "camera", 
  mozAutoGainControl: {}, 
  mozNoiseSuppression: {}, 
  viewportHeight: {}, 
  viewportOffsetX: {}, 
  ...
}
```

that only contains information about a video stream (funnily I requested an audio stream) and no bandwidth details. There are no other streams for the arrays in the example above.
Do you know where I need to look for the current quality/bandwidth of a MediaStream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use the RTCPeerConnection.getStats() API, search for the [bytesReceived](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcreceivedrtpstreamstats-bytesreceived) and then calculate the bitrate as the difference of bytesReceived between two calls. [This](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/) shows a complete example.

Comment: Many thanks! I thought it's more visible, but the solution is fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the SDP to be `stereo` and increase the `maxaveragebitrate`:

```
let answer = await peer.conn.createAnswer(offerOptions);
answer.sdp = answer.sdp.replace('useinbandfec=1', 'useinbandfec=1; stereo=1; maxaveragebitrate=510000');
await peer.conn.setLocalDescription(answer);
```

Then I get a potential maximum bitrate of 520kb/s for stereo, which is 260kps per channel. Actual bitrate depends on the speed of your network and strength of your signal though :)